# Bottom sheet not inflating in activity

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments

I have this bottom sheet that i wanted to inflate on button click in my DialogsActivity.java but whenever i run my app and click the button nothing happens.

this is the code where it should've inflated the bottom sheet.

DialogsActivity.java

```
    floatingButtonContainer = new FrameLayout(context);
            floatingButtonContainer.setVisibility(onlySelect && initialDialogsType != 10 || folderId != 0 ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
            contentView.addView(floatingButtonContainer, LayoutHelper.createFrame((Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21 ? 56 : 60) + 20, (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21 ? 56 : 60) + 20, (LocaleController.isRTL ? Gravity.LEFT : Gravity.RIGHT) | Gravity.BOTTOM, LocaleController.isRTL ? 4 : 0, 0, LocaleController.isRTL ? 0 : 4, 0));
            
     floatingButtonContainer.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                

                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
                inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_bottom_sheet,null);
    
          
            });
```

This is the BottomSheetFrag.java

```
public class BottomSheetFrag extends BottomSheetDialogFragment {

    public BottomSheetFrag(){

    }


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_bottom_sheet, container, false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You `BottomSheetFrag` code looks fine.

You dont need to inflate `BottomSheetFrag` in activity, instead you should use `Fragment Transaction` for this purpose.

Please update your `DialogActivity` code as below.

```
    BottomSheetFrag bottomSheet = new BottomSheetFrag();

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

    fragmentManager.executePendingTransactions();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

    if (bottomSheet.isAdded()) {
        FragmentTransaction removeTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        removeTransaction.remove(bottomSheet);
        removeTransaction.commitNow();
    }

    fragmentTransaction.add(bottomSheet, "tag");
    fragmentTransaction.commitNow();
```